# PHP: When are settings in .user.ini get applied when using php-fpm?

Tags: php, configuration, config

I'm using Apache with php-fpm on a RHEL8 system. php-fpm was installed from [remi repo](https://blog.remirepo.net/) in version 7.2.

I've added a file [`.user.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) in a web accessible folder to set `memory_limit=256M` (default of /etc/php.ini is 128M). It seems to work. But I detected that the value does 'not always' seems to be applied immediately if I change it. I checked that by repeatedly calling a page that outputs `phpinfo();`. Sometimes the value is changed, sometimes not.

I guess that it is php-fpm with its process pool (if I did understand that correctly). New processes will have the new value. Old values the old one. And if a page gets called, you never know which process actually responds.

I think reloading php-fmp (`systemctl reload php-fpm.service`) resets those processes and each has the updated value.

Can anyone explain how it works exactly? What is important to know, about `.user.ini` and php-fpm? Can it be that some request will use the old value forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked documentation page, see [user_ini.cache_ttl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.user-ini.cache-ttl) which define the TTL (Time To Live) of .user.ini file.

- Large value is better for performance, so for production
- Small value can be useful for development

Default value is 300, 5' which can seems long.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And is `systemctl reload php-fpm.service` a way to force applying the values immediately?